# Lagrange multiplier fails to work?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I have been asked to find the extreme values of the function $f(x,y) = x^2 - y^2 $ in the domain $D = \{(x,y) : x^2 + y^2 = 1\}$. When applying the method of Lagrange Multipliers, there is a problem because you get: $2x = \lambda (2x)$ and $-2y = \lambda(2y)$, which doesn't seem to make sense to me, because then $\lambda$ does not have a well-defined value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No contradiction. So, indeed $$\begin{cases}
2x+2\lambda x=0\\
-2y+2\lambda y=0\\
x^2+y^2=1
\end{cases}$$

If $x\neq 0$, you get $\lambda =-1$, and thus, the 2nd equation gives $y=0$. Therefore, with the 3rd equation, you get $x^2=1$, and thus $x=\pm 1$. Same if $y\neq 0$, you get $x=0$, and thus $y=\pm1$. So you have to check what happen for $(x,y)\in \{(0,\pm1), (\pm 1,0)\}$

Comment: Ah I see, thanks